# Incorrect sizing of canvas context

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have two canvas blocks, one sized with inline attributes, and the other sized with CSS.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canv_in" width="400" height="400"> </canvas>
<canvas id="canv_ss"> </canvas>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
     background-color : rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}

#canv_ss {
    width : 400px;
    height: 400px;        
}
```

The canvases both have the same dimensions, but when I try to draw the same rectangle in both of them, I get a different result. Here's the js:

```
var canvasElems = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
var canvasContext;

for(i = 0; i < canvasElems.length; ++i) {
    canvasContext = canvasElems[i].getContext("2d");
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 225, 1.0)";
    canvasContext.fillRect(120, 10, 150, 150);
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: Canvas is weird]

So, my question is: how do we size the rectangle as intended, while keeping my element styles in CSS? Is that not possible? Why is the rectangle on the right behaving strangely?

Comment: The second one has the default dimensions. It is then scaled/stretched (non-uniformly) to 400x400. You can set the number of pixels on the canvas either (a) with the width/height _attributes_ in the html, or with the width/height attributes in the JS. For what its worth - your first one _doesn't_ have inline styles applied - they're attributes of the canvas, **not** attributes of its style.

Comment: Interesting, so I should avoid sizing `canvas` in css always?

Comment: Depends on your needs. I often size it in css (e.g: width: 100%), then query the element for its on-screen size in JS, followed by setting its pixel dimensions to match the space it consumes on-screen. There are definitely uses for each way (object attributes vs css attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width attribute defaults to `300px` and the height to `150px`. Adding a stylesheet to the element merely scales the box to that size and does not extend the coordinate space.

> A canvas element can be sized arbitrarily by a style sheet, its bitmap
>   is then subject to the 'object-fit' CSS property.

The intrinsic dimensions of the canvas element when it represents embedded content are equal to the dimensions of the element's bitmap.

The `HTML` attributes (`width` and `height`) sets the canvas dimensions, which determines how objects are measured on the canvas.

The CSS style sets the canvas display size, which determines dimensions of canvas on browser. If the display size is different from the dimensions, the canvas will be stretched when drawn.

When a canvas element represents embedded content, it provides a paint source whose width is the element's intrinsic `width`, whose `height` is the element's intrinsic height, and whose appearance is the element's bitmap.

Whenever the `width` and `height` content attributes are set, removed, changed, or redundantly set to the value they already have, if the canvas context mode is `direct-2d`, the user agent must set bitmap dimensions to the numeric values of the width and height content attributes.

The `width` and `height` IDL attributes must reflect the respective content attributes of the same name, with the same defaults.

**Conclusion**

There is a difference between the canvas dimensions and the canvas display size.

If you only define the dimensions, that will also be used as the display size, i.e. the canvas is drawn at scale 1:1.

If you only define the display size, the dimensions will get the default value 300 times 150.

[You have more information here.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-width)